# Which regexp php is using for filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)?

Tags: php, regex

`filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` seems to be great way to detect if `$url` contains url or not. Is there any way to see what regular expression this function uses for detecting?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think they’re using a regular expression?

Comment: @Gumbo, probably no. I have no too much experience and knowledge to see source of php libs/core. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It uses something else then a regex. In C, it checks the return of the `php_url_parse_ex()`(C) function, which you can see at: [ext/standard/url.c, line 97](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/url.c?revision=300501&view=markup#l97), called at [ext/filter/logical_filters.c, line 440](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/filter/logical_filters.c?revision=297353&view=markup#l440).

In these terms: if you call `parse_url()`(PHP) in PHP, and perform the same checks as in `php_filter_validate_url()`(C), you'd have the same output.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is similar to the URL parsing.

```
$pattern = "/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i";
```